# How do I save the relative row or column frequencies after tab twoway in a matrix?

Tags: stata

If I run this code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tab rep78 foreign, nofreq row matcell(freqs)
matrix list freqs
```

it's clear that tab only saved the actual counts in each cell, not the frequencies that were calculated and displayed with the nofreq row options. How do I save these relative frequencies in a matrix? I can back them out manually, but since Stata has already calculated them, there should be a way to save them.

Also posted on [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1292001-how-do-i-save-the-relative-row-or-column-frequencies-after-tab-twoway-in-a-matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate matrices in Stata, but Mata is richer for this purpose. It can be used calculator-style.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tab rep78 foreign, nofreq row matcell(freqs)

    Repair |
    Record |       Car type
      1978 |  Domestic    Foreign |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |    100.00       0.00 |    100.00 
         2 |    100.00       0.00 |    100.00 
         3 |     90.00      10.00 |    100.00 
         4 |     50.00      50.00 |    100.00 
         5 |     18.18      81.82 |    100.00 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     69.57      30.43 |    100.00 


. matrix list freqs

freqs[5,2]
    c1  c2
r1   2   0
r2   8   0
r3  27   3
r4   9   9
r5   2   9

. mata 

: freqs = st_matrix("freqs")
: freqs :/ rowsum(freqs)
: freqs :/ colsum(freqs)
```

You can push any of these matrices back to Stata, naturally.

Comment: So, how can I add the colsum to freqs matrix?

Comment: Already answered.